# iPhone: Email API MFMailComposeViewController crashes on Device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I get the below given crash log when I try to use MFMailComposeViewController on device.

It opens modal view when I try to run it on simulator.

This is the code I am using:

`stringHTML` and `html` are HTML strings.

`stringHTML` is of type NSString and `html` is of type NSMutableString.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailController setSubject:@"Email"];
NSLog(@"%@",html);
NSString *stringHTML=html;
NSLog(@"%@",stringHTML);
[mailController setMessageBody:stringHTML isHTML:YES];
[self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
[mailController release];
```

What could be wrong?

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <QuizReportsView: 0x411af0>.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x3737364f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x33a30c5d objc_exception_throw + 24
2   UIKit                               0x31350fcf -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:withTransition:] + 546
3   UIKit                               0x31350cd7 -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] + 58
4   Vocab                               0x0007d1bf -[QuizReportsView actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:] + 270
5   UIKit                               0x313c603d -[UIActionSheet(Private) _buttonClicked:] + 192
6   CoreFoundation                      0x372e3571 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 24
7   UIKit                               0x312c3ec9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 84
8   UIKit                               0x312c3e69 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 32
9   UIKit                               0x312c3e3b -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 38
10  UIKit                               0x312c3b8d -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 356
11  UIKit                               0x312c4423 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 342
12  UIKit                               0x312c2bf5 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 368
13  UIKit                               0x312c256f -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 262
14  UIKit                               0x312ab313 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 298
15  UIKit                               0x312aac53 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5090
16  GraphicsServices                    0x31c36e77 PurpleEventCallback + 666
17  CoreFoundation                      0x3734aa97 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 26
18  CoreFoundation                      0x3734c83f __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 166
19  CoreFoundation                      0x3734d60d __CFRunLoopRun + 520
20  CoreFoundation                      0x372ddec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
21  CoreFoundation                      0x372dddcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
22  GraphicsServices                    0x31c3641f GSEventRunModal + 114
23  GraphicsServices                    0x31c364cb GSEventRun + 62
24  UIKit                               0x312d5d69 -[UIApplication _run] + 404
25  UIKit                               0x312d3807 UIApplicationMain + 670
26  Vocab                               0x00002223 main + 82
27  Vocab                               0x000021cc start + 40
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From error It's clear , you are presenting a `nil`  modal view controller.

Check for the object of  `MFMailComposeViewController` whether It's being constructed correctly or not.

**And Aslo** `MFMailComposeViewController` available in iOS 3.0 and later.

Try with below code

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
if(mailController)
{
    mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
   [mailController setSubject:@"Email"];
    NSLog(@"%@",html);
    NSString *stringHTML=html;
    NSLog(@"%@",stringHTML);
    [mailController setMessageBody:stringHTML isHTML:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
    [mailController release];
}
```

For more check below .

[Application tried to present a nil modal view...](http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/84/topics/3178)

[Problem with Modal View Controller](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=904771)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did work :) Mail Account was not set up in my device. So Allocation was not taking place.

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
//check if device is configured to send mails
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
  MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
  if(mailController)
  {
    mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
   [mailController setSubject:@"Email"];
    NSLog(@"%@",html);
    NSString *stringHTML=html;
    NSLog(@"%@",stringHTML);
    [mailController setMessageBody:stringHTML isHTML:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
    [mailController release];
  }
}
```

Comment: @Deepak what is your mail Id?. I need a little bit of your help.